# How do I fix MySql's LEFT JOIN Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) Bug?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, query-optimization

I think I ran into [this MySql bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69721), but the solution references a comment that no longer exists. Does anyone know what the solution is?

My particular use case involves a game with rounds. I want find all the (game, round) pairs where there are no "Inaction" events after an "Action" event. This is my query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(id) AS id,
            game_id,
            round
        FROM event
        WHERE
            type_of="Action"
        GROUP BY
            game_id, round
    ) AS last_action
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            MAX(id) AS id,
            game_id,
            round
        FROM event
        WHERE
            type_of="Inaction"
        GROUP BY
            game_id, round                  
    ) AS last_inaction
        USING
            (game_id, round)
WHERE
    last_inaction.id IS NULL
    OR last_action.id > last_inaction.id;
```

This runs very slowly and has an EXPLAIN including `Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)`. But if I edit the query's WHERE statement to the functionally equivalent

```
WHERE
    last_inaction.id IS NULL
    OR last_action.id > last_inaction.id + 0;
```

the query executes almost instantaneously and does not include the `Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do what you want with a single aggregate query, using a `HAVING` clause for filtering:

```
SELECT game_id, round
FROM event
WHERE type_of IN ('Action', 'Inaction')
GROUP BY game_id, round
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN type_of = 'Inaction' THEN id END) 
        < MAX(CASE WHEN type_of = 'Action' THEN id END)
    OR (
        MAX(CASE WHEN type_of = 'Inaction' THEN id END) IS NULL
        AND MAX(CASE WHEN type_of = 'Action' THEN id END) IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: This almost works! When checking if Inaction is null, you also have to check that Action isn't null. I have submitted an edit request.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should mark this best answer. GMB solved my use case, but didn't answer the larger question re the bug.

Comment: @trexinf14s: ok, I see. I edited my answer accordingly - and I also added a `WHERE` cause, which will possibly make the query more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  Set `block_nested_loop=OFF` in `optimizer_switch`

Plan B:  Simplify the query and speed it up:

```
SELECT  b.game_id, b.round
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  MAX(id) AS id
            FROM  event
            WHERE  type_of IN ('Action', 'Inaction')
            GROUP BY  game_id, round 
        ) AS a
    JOIN  event b USING(id)
    WHERE  b.type_of = 'Action';
```

(My version gives fewer columns, but the rest seem to be redundant or irrelevant.)

And add a composite index:

```
INDEX(game_id, round, type_of, id)
```

(I assume that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `event`.)